# Bootstrap element leaving responsive card

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this issue, I've got two triangles that are to be side by side and have. a little gap, However on resize they move about freely and don't stay inside the card.

How would I go about fixing this?

Heres the JS Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vnpoL6t0/

Heres the code:

```
.uppertri{
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
    width: 217px;
    height: 217px;
}
.lowertri{
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
    width: 217px;
    height: 217px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 3rem;
    top: 1.7rem;
}

<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <a class="wood" href="/get_wood/1">
          <div class="card">
            <!-- <div class="premium"></div> -->
            <div class="card-body" align="center">
                <img class="uppertri" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="Logo">
                <img class="lowertri" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="Logo">
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
          <a class="wood" href="/get_wood/2">
          <div class="card">
            <!-- <div class="premium"></div> -->
            <div class="card-body" align="center">
                <img class="uppertri" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="Logo">
                <img class="lowertri" src="https://loremflickr.com/320/240" alt="Logo">
            </div>
          </div>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `fix height` and `fix width` so that you can scale    images while resizing

you can set `right` instead of `left` in `lowertri` and set `uppertri` to `left: 0` if you want. so that both triangles stay inside the div

```
.uppertri {
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
   clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 0 100%);
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 50%;
 }
.lowertri {
   -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
   clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%);
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 50%;
}
.card-body {
  min-height: 170px;
}
```

Comment: That works great for the triangles sticking with the box but it doesn't help the size of the triangle :/

Comment: @SamRoberts please check my updated answer, please let me know if you need changes